# words not highlighted as per requirement mark.js

Tags: javascript

I used mark.js to highlight some words that i want in a string. But for some weird reason , it's not highlighting all the words i want.[image]

```
<html>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mark.js/7.0.0/mark.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div>Hyundai Samsung car jeeps jeep jeep jeep Mercedes-Benz Nike Apple Nissan Scion!</div>
</body>

<script>
var brands =   ["car" , "jeeps" , "jeep"];

var instance = new Mark(document.querySelector("body"));

instance.mark(brands, {
    accuracy: "exactly",
    separateWordSearch: false
});


</script>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate more? The code is working as it is, so it might be something else. http://jsfiddle.net/zpgubjwt

Comment: I have no idea , why it's working in the fiddle. I have included the code and the screenshot.

Comment: Could you try `var instance = new Mark(document.querySelector("div"));` instead of `var instance = new Mark(document.querySelector("body"));` to see if it works?

Comment: No , not working.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mark.js/8.11.1/jquery.mark.es6.js"></script>
```

inclusion of this cdn made it work.